# Uploading image: temp file / name is not created

Tags: php

I'm hit with a nasty bug.
I have a form system that submits image from jquery / ajax to a php script.
This script task is to take the temp file and move it with a permanant name.

The major problem is that it works for most of images, except a single one where the temp file is not created. I can also see in the file array for that file an 'error' key with value of 1.

Here is the php code

```
 public function uploadImageInTempDir(): array
    {

        $imagePath = [];
        $slugify = new Slugify();
        $currentYear = date( 'Y' );
        $currentMonth = date( 'm' );

        # Save currently uploaded file as a concrete file, instead of a temporary file.
        # We iterate to access the file in question because it is the only way to access files in $_FILES .
        # But there always is only 1 file in the array as sent from the frontend.
        foreach ( $this->files as $file ) {
            if ( ! empty( $file[ 'name' ] ) ) {
                $imageName = $slugify->slugify( $file[ 'name' ] );
                $randomString = time();
                $imageType = Utilities::getFileExtension( $file[ 'name' ] );
                $finalImageName = $imageName . '-' . $randomString . '.' . $imageType;
                $saveTargetTmp = Settings::SAVE_IMAGE_TEMP_PATH . $finalImageName;

                move_uploaded_file( $file[ 'tmp_name' ], $saveTargetTmp );
                # We add year/month to filename to store each file in corresponding year/month directory structure.
                $imagePath[ "path" ] = $currentYear . $currentMonth . '/' . $finalImageName;
            }
        }

        # We pass back to the frontend the final path of the image which will be in the form of:
        # /year/month/filename-random.ext . Note that currently image is NOT in its final
        # destination. It will have to be moved there when user finally posts the full form.
        return $imagePath;
    }
```

My first question is: do you know how to interpret the error code in the file array which shows 1 ? It doesn't throw any exception or error I can catch globally:
[image]

Second, do you see why this error happens ?

Facts:

- it works with all kind of images with similar names.
- it's not a size problem
- The script receives information as you can see form the image it got the filename.

Here is the frontend code, it reports succesful upload:

```
$.ajax( {
                url        : '/blog/upload-image',
                type       : form.attr( 'method' ),
                contentType: false, // obligatoire pour de l'upload
                processData: false, // obligatoire pour de l'upload
                dataType   : 'json', // selon le retour attendu
                data       : data
            } ).done( function( response ) {
                console.log( `Upload image success: ${idOfUploadedImage}` )
                console.log( response )

                // front end tasks

            } ).fail( function( response ) {
                console.log( "Upload image error: ", response );
            } ).always( function() {
                console.log( "Upload image complete" );
            } );
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: Please answer with this question and I will chose you. I could have sweared It was not a size problem but it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upload errors are listed [here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php), the value `1` is the following error:

> UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE
>
> Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the
> upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.

So your image file is bigger than the maximum set in the php.ini.

Comment: thank you. Anyway to have this bubble up to be caught by exception / error handler ?

Comment: Not by PHP itself, when your script is invoked, the upload is already finished and the result known. You'd need to check for errors yourself and throw a exception if something was wrong.